# Negative days in account

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have a website where people can sell products. Each time they add a product they have to pay me 10 cent. Every user has something which you can compare to a bank account. So when they add a product their account goes -10 cent. Each user can only have a negative account for x amount of days.

So I need an algorithm that can calculate how many days an account has been negative.

The data looks like:

```
var data = [
  { amount: -10, ago: 15 },
  { amount: 10,  ago: 10 },
  { amount: -10, ago: 5 }
];
```

So this account has been negative for 5 days. ( In my app I am using dates but to keep things simple I am using "days ago" here. )

An other example:

```
var data = [
  { amount: -10, ago: 15 },
  { amount: -10, ago: 10 },
  { amount: -10, ago: 5 }
];
```

This account has been negative for 15 days.

I already solved the problem myself but maybe there is a more elegant solution?

My solution to this problem: http://jsfiddle.net/SK2By/1/

Empty template to test your algorithm: http://jsfiddle.net/SK2By/

Comment: If you have a working solution, if suggest asking for improvements at http://codereview.stackexchange.com instead of here.

Comment: Upvote for the template with failing testcases. Epic win.

Comment: Although, why is `solution3` 15? If the account was positive 5 days ago?

Comment: Can you guarantee the data will always be in chronological order?

Comment: @Hamish amount isn't the state of the account it's a transaction. The +10 5 days ago put the account into -10 which still is negative.

Comment: In the first code block, isn't it 10 days? I mean, days `[15, 10>` and `[5, 0>`.

Comment: @Pickels, so we assume a zero balance, and the amounts indicate a complete history of debits/credits?

Comment: @Pickels Oh. That's really confusing.

Comment: @Will Klein That is correct. The total of all the amounts give you the current balance of the account.

Comment: One thing I'd like to point out in your original approach... you put "var b, previous;" inside your while loop. Please be aware that JavaScript uses function level scoping, so those variables are "hoisted" up to the top of the function. It's good practice in JavaScript to declare all your vars at the beginning of the function. This is significantly different than other languages that have block level scoping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another approach to consider:

```
var negativeDays = function (data) {

    var i, balance = 0, daysNegative = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        balance += data[i].amount;

        if (balance < 0) {
            if (daysNegative === 0) {
                daysNegative = data[i].ago;
            }
        } else {
            daysNegative = 0;
        }
    }

    return daysNegative;
};
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/willslab/SK2By/7/

Comment: Wow, very nice and a lot less complicated than what I had.

Comment: You're welcome! Would you accept the answer if you agree? Of course, if someone else comes along with something better, you can always change the accepted answer. I'd be interested to see something else too.